# How to prove a set is convex

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

Let $E = \{x\mid (x - c)^{T} P^{-1} (x-c) \le 1  \}$, where $P$ is symmetric positive definite. Show that $E$ is convex.

Here is what I did. 
It seems like $E$ is an ellipsoid. We want to show that if $x, y \in E$, then $(1-\theta)x+\theta y \in E$, for $0\le\theta\le1$.

Suppose $x, y \in E$. By definition we have

$$
(x-c)^{T}P^{-1}(x-c) \le 1
$$
$$
(y-c)^{T}P^{-1}(y-c) \le 1
$$

Expanding equations we get

$$
 x^{T}P^{-1}x - 2c^{T}P^{-1}x +c^{T}P^{-1}c \le 1
$$

$$
 y^{T}P^{-1}y - 2c^{T}P^{-1}y +c^{T}P^{-1}c \le 1
$$

Multiply both sides of first equation by $1-\theta$ and second by $\theta$, add them up, then we are done?

My question is why do we need the fact that $P$ is symmetric positive definite?

Comment: I'm rather ignorant of such things, but does this have to do with convex optimization, or just geometric convexity?

Comment: Note that for any norm $\| \cdot \|$, $\{ x \mid \| x - c \| \leq 1 \}$ is convex.  We have here the special case where $\| y \| = \sqrt{ y^T P^{-1} y }$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't do it.  You need to consider
$$
((1-\theta)x+\theta y-c)^T P^{-1} ((1-\theta)x+\theta y-c).
$$
This is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}} ((1-\theta)x+\theta y-[(1-\theta) c + \theta c])^T P^{-1} ((1-\theta)x+\theta y-[(1-\theta) c + \theta c]) \\[10pt]
& = (1-\theta)^2 \underbrace{(x-c)^T P^{-1}(x-c)} + \theta^2 \underbrace{(y-c)^T P^{-1}(y-c)} + 2\theta(1-\theta)\underbrace{(x-c)^T P^{-1} (y-c)}.
\end{align}
$$
The third term is subject to a Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:
$$
((x-c)^T P^{-1} (y-c))^2 \le \Big((x-c)^T P^{-1} (x-c)\Big)\Big((y-c)^T P^{-1} (y-c) \Big).
$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!